# LibGDX Gifdecoder

Tags: java, libgdx, gif

I want to use gifs in libGDX and found a gif decoder to do so. But the loading time when displaying gifs is way too long. Is there a possibility to preload gifs with some kind of loading screen? I am using the following gif decoder:

```
public class GifDecoder {
/**
 * File read status: No errors.
 */
public static final int STATUS_OK = 0;
/**
 * File read status: Error decoding file (may be partially decoded)
 */
public static final int STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR = 1;
/**
 * File read status: Unable to open source.
 */
public static final int STATUS_OPEN_ERROR = 2;
/** max decoder pixel stack size */
protected static final int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 4096;
protected InputStream in;
protected int status;
protected int width; // full image width
protected int height; // full image height
protected boolean gctFlag; // global color table used
protected int gctSize; // size of global color table
protected int loopCount = 1; // iterations; 0 = repeat forever
protected int[] gct; // global color table
protected int[] lct; // local color table
protected int[] act; // active color table
protected int bgIndex; // background color index
protected int bgColor; // background color
protected int lastBgColor; // previous bg color
protected int pixelAspect; // pixel aspect ratio
protected boolean lctFlag; // local color table flag
protected boolean interlace; // interlace flag
protected int lctSize; // local color table size
protected int ix, iy, iw, ih; // current image rectangle
protected int lrx, lry, lrw, lrh;
protected DixieMap image; // current frame
protected DixieMap lastPixmap; // previous frame
protected byte[] block = new byte[256]; // current data block
protected int blockSize = 0; // block size last graphic control extension info
protected int dispose = 0; // 0=no action; 1=leave in place; 2=restore to bg; 3=restore to prev
protected int lastDispose = 0;
protected boolean transparency = false; // use transparent color
protected int delay = 0; // delay in milliseconds
protected int transIndex; // transparent color index
// LZW decoder working arrays
protected short[] prefix;
protected byte[] suffix;
protected byte[] pixelStack;
protected byte[] pixels;
protected Vector<GifFrame> frames; // frames read from current file
protected int frameCount;

private static class DixieMap extends Pixmap {
    DixieMap(int w, int h, Pixmap.Format f) {
        super(w, h, f);
    }

    DixieMap(int[] data, int w, int h, Pixmap.Format f) {
        super(w, h, f);

        int x, y;

        for(y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            for(x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                int pxl_ARGB8888 = data[x + y * w];
                int pxl_RGBA8888 =
                        ((pxl_ARGB8888 >> 24) & 0x000000ff) | ((pxl_ARGB8888 << 8) & 0xffffff00);
                // convert ARGB8888 > RGBA8888
                drawPixel(x, y, pxl_RGBA8888);
            }
        }
    }

    void getPixels(int[] pixels, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        java.nio.ByteBuffer bb = getPixels();

        int k, l;

        for(k = y;  k < y + height; k++) {
            int _offset = offset;
            for(l = x; l < x + width; l++) {
                int pxl = bb.getInt(4 * (l + k * width));

                // convert RGBA8888 > ARGB8888
                pixels[_offset++] = ((pxl >> 8) & 0x00ffffff) | ((pxl << 24) & 0xff000000);
            }
            offset += stride;
        }
    }
}

private static class GifFrame {
    public GifFrame(DixieMap im, int del) {
        image = im;
        delay = del;
    }

    public DixieMap image;
    public int delay;
}

/**
 * Gets display duration for specified frame.
 *
 * @param n
 *          int index of frame
 * @return delay in milliseconds
 */
public int getDelay(int n) {
    delay = -1;
    if ((n >= 0) && (n < frameCount)) {
        delay = frames.elementAt(n).delay;
    }
    return delay;
}

/**
 * Gets the number of frames read from file.
 *
 * @return frame count
 */
public int getFrameCount() {
    return frameCount;
}

/**
 * Gets the first (or only) image read.
 *
 * @return BufferedPixmap containing first frame, or null if none.
 */
public Pixmap getPixmap() {
    return getFrame(0);
}

/**
 * Gets the "Netscape" iteration count, if any. A count of 0 means repeat indefinitely.
 *
 * @return iteration count if one was specified, else 1.
 */
public int getLoopCount() {
    return loopCount;
}

/**
 * Creates new frame image from current data (and previous frames as specified by their disposition codes).
 */
protected void setPixels() {
    // expose destination image's pixels as int array
    int[] dest = new int[width * height];
    // fill in starting image contents based on last image's dispose code
    if (lastDispose > 0) {
        if (lastDispose == 3) {
            // use image before last
            int n = frameCount - 2;
            if (n > 0) {
                lastPixmap = getFrame(n - 1);
            } else {
                lastPixmap = null;
            }
        }
        if (lastPixmap != null) {
            lastPixmap.getPixels(dest, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
            // copy pixels
            if (lastDispose == 2) {
                // fill last image rect area with background color
                int c = 0;
                if (!transparency) {
                    c = lastBgColor;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < lrh; i++) {
                    int n1 = (lry + i) * width + lrx;
                    int n2 = n1 + lrw;
                    for (int k = n1; k < n2; k++) {
                        dest[k] = c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // copy each source line to the appropriate place in the destination
    int pass = 1;
    int inc = 8;
    int iline = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ih; i++) {
        int line = i;
        if (interlace) {
            if (iline >= ih) {
                pass++;
                switch (pass) {
                    case 2:
                        iline = 4;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        iline = 2;
                        inc = 4;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        iline = 1;
                        inc = 2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            line = iline;
            iline += inc;
        }
        line += iy;
        if (line < height) {
            int k = line * width;
            int dx = k + ix; // start of line in dest
            int dlim = dx + iw; // end of dest line
            if ((k + width) < dlim) {
                dlim = k + width; // past dest edge
            }
            int sx = i * iw; // start of line in source
            while (dx < dlim) {
                // map color and insert in destination
                int index = ((int) pixels[sx++]) & 0xff;
                int c = act[index];
                if (c != 0) {
                    dest[dx] = c;
                }
                dx++;
            }
        }
    }
    image = new DixieMap(dest, width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    //Pixmap.createPixmap(dest, width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
}

/**
 * Gets the image contents of frame n.
 *
 * @return BufferedPixmap representation of frame, or null if n is invalid.
 */
public DixieMap getFrame(int n) {
    if (frameCount <= 0)
        return null;
    n = n % frameCount;
    return ((GifFrame) frames.elementAt(n)).image;
}

/**
 * Reads GIF image from stream
 *
 * @param is
 *          containing GIF file.
 * @return read status code (0 = no errors)
 */
public int read(InputStream is) {
    init();
    if (is != null) {
        in = is;
        readHeader();
        if (!err()) {
            readContents();
            if (frameCount < 0) {
                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
        }
    } else {
        status = STATUS_OPEN_ERROR;
    }
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return status;
}

/**
 * Decodes LZW image data into pixel array. Adapted from John Cristy's BitmapMagick.
 */
protected void decodeBitmapData() {
    int nullCode = -1;
    int npix = iw * ih;
    int available, clear, code_mask, code_size, end_of_information, in_code, old_code, bits, code, count, i, datum, data_size, first, top, bi, pi;
    if ((pixels == null) || (pixels.length < npix)) {
        pixels = new byte[npix]; // allocate new pixel array
    }
    if (prefix == null) {
        prefix = new short[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    }
    if (suffix == null) {
        suffix = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    }
    if (pixelStack == null) {
        pixelStack = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE + 1];
    }
    // Initialize GIF data stream decoder.
    data_size = read();
    clear = 1 << data_size;
    end_of_information = clear + 1;
    available = clear + 2;
    old_code = nullCode;
    code_size = data_size + 1;
    code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
    for (code = 0; code < clear; code++) {
        prefix[code] = 0; // XXX ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        suffix[code] = (byte) code;
    }
    // Decode GIF pixel stream.
    datum = bits = count = first = top = pi = bi = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < npix;) {
        if (top == 0) {
            if (bits < code_size) {
                // Load bytes until there are enough bits for a code.
                if (count == 0) {
                    // Read a new data block.
                    count = readBlock();
                    if (count <= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    bi = 0;
                }
                datum += (((int) block[bi]) & 0xff) << bits;
                bits += 8;
                bi++;
                count--;
                continue;
            }
            // Get the next code.
            code = datum & code_mask;
            datum >>= code_size;
            bits -= code_size;
            // Interpret the code
            if ((code > available) || (code == end_of_information)) {
                break;
            }
            if (code == clear) {
                // Reset decoder.
                code_size = data_size + 1;
                code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
                available = clear + 2;
                old_code = nullCode;
                continue;
            }
            if (old_code == nullCode) {
                pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                old_code = code;
                first = code;
                continue;
            }
            in_code = code;
            if (code == available) {
                pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                code = old_code;
            }
            while (code > clear) {
                pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                code = prefix[code];
            }
            first = ((int) suffix[code]) & 0xff;
            // Add a new string to the string table,
            if (available >= MAX_STACK_SIZE) {
                break;
            }
            pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
            prefix[available] = (short) old_code;
            suffix[available] = (byte) first;
            available++;
            if (((available & code_mask) == 0) && (available < MAX_STACK_SIZE)) {
                code_size++;
                code_mask += available;
            }
            old_code = in_code;
        }
        // Pop a pixel off the pixel stack.
        top--;
        pixels[pi++] = pixelStack[top];
        i++;
    }
    for (i = pi; i < npix; i++) {
        pixels[i] = 0; // clear missing pixels
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if an error was encountered during reading/decoding
 */
protected boolean err() {
    return status != STATUS_OK;
}

/**
 * Initializes or re-initializes reader
 */
protected void init() {
    status = STATUS_OK;
    frameCount = 0;
    frames = new Vector<GifFrame>();
    gct = null;
    lct = null;
}

/**
 * Reads a single byte from the input stream.
 */
protected int read() {
    int curByte = 0;
    try {
        curByte = in.read();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
    }
    return curByte;
}

/**
 * Reads next variable length block from input.
 *
 * @return number of bytes stored in "buffer"
 */
protected int readBlock() {
    blockSize = read();
    int n = 0;
    if (blockSize > 0) {
        try {
            int count = 0;
            while (n < blockSize) {
                count = in.read(block, n, blockSize - n);
                if (count == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                n += count;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (n < blockSize) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

/**
 * Reads color table as 256 RGB integer values
 *
 * @param ncolors
 *          int number of colors to read
 * @return int array containing 256 colors (packed ARGB with full alpha)
 */
protected int[] readColorTable(int ncolors) {
    int nbytes = 3 * ncolors;
    int[] tab = null;
    byte[] c = new byte[nbytes];
    int n = 0;
    try {
        n = in.read(c);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (n < nbytes) {
        status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
    } else {
        tab = new int[256]; // max size to avoid bounds checks
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < ncolors) {
            int r = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
            int g = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
            int b = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
            tab[i++] = 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        }
    }
    return tab;
}

/**
 * Main file parser. Reads GIF content blocks.
 */
protected void readContents() {
    // read GIF file content blocks
    boolean done = false;
    while (!(done || err())) {
        int code = read();
        switch (code) {
            case 0x2C: // image separator
                readBitmap();
                break;
            case 0x21: // extension
                code = read();
                switch (code) {
                    case 0xf9: // graphics control extension
                        readGraphicControlExt();
                        break;
                    case 0xff: // application extension
                        readBlock();
                        String app = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                            app += (char) block[i];
                        }
                        if (app.equals("NETSCAPE2.0")) {
                            readNetscapeExt();
                        } else {
                            skip(); // don't care
                        }
                        break;
                    case 0xfe:// comment extension
                        skip();
                        break;
                    case 0x01:// plain text extension
                        skip();
                        break;
                    default: // uninteresting extension
                        skip();
                }
                break;
            case 0x3b: // terminator
                done = true;
                break;
            case 0x00: // bad byte, but keep going and see what happens break;
            default:
                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Reads Graphics Control Extension values
 */
protected void readGraphicControlExt() {
    read(); // block size
    int packed = read(); // packed fields
    dispose = (packed & 0x1c) >> 2; // disposal method
    if (dispose == 0) {
        dispose = 1; // elect to keep old image if discretionary
    }
    transparency = (packed & 1) != 0;
    delay = readShort() * 10; // delay in milliseconds
    transIndex = read(); // transparent color index
    read(); // block terminator
}

/**
 * Reads GIF file header information.
 */
protected void readHeader() {
    String id = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        id += (char) read();
    }
    if (!id.startsWith("GIF")) {
        status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        return;
    }
    readLSD();
    if (gctFlag && !err()) {
        gct = readColorTable(gctSize);
        bgColor = gct[bgIndex];
    }
}

/**
 * Reads next frame image
 */
protected void readBitmap() {
    ix = readShort(); // (sub)image position & size
    iy = readShort();
    iw = readShort();
    ih = readShort();
    int packed = read();
    lctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 - local color table flag interlace
    lctSize = (int) Math.pow(2, (packed & 0x07) + 1);
    // 3 - sort flag
    // 4-5 - reserved lctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 - local color
    // table size
    interlace = (packed & 0x40) != 0;
    if (lctFlag) {
        lct = readColorTable(lctSize); // read table
        act = lct; // make local table active
    } else {
        act = gct; // make global table active
        if (bgIndex == transIndex) {
            bgColor = 0;
        }
    }
    int save = 0;
    if (transparency) {
        save = act[transIndex];
        act[transIndex] = 0; // set transparent color if specified
    }
    if (act == null) {
        status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR; // no color table defined
    }
    if (err()) {
        return;
    }
    decodeBitmapData(); // decode pixel data
    skip();
    if (err()) {
        return;
    }
    frameCount++;
    // create new image to receive frame data
    image = new DixieMap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    setPixels(); // transfer pixel data to image
    frames.addElement(new GifFrame(image, delay)); // add image to frame
    // list
    if (transparency) {
        act[transIndex] = save;
    }
    resetFrame();
}

/**
 * Reads Logical Screen Descriptor
 */
protected void readLSD() {
    // logical screen size
    width = readShort();
    height = readShort();
    // packed fields
    int packed = read();
    gctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 : global color table flag
    // 2-4 : color resolution
    // 5 : gct sort flag
    gctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 : gct size
    bgIndex = read(); // background color index
    pixelAspect = read(); // pixel aspect ratio
}

/**
 * Reads Netscape extenstion to obtain iteration count
 */
protected void readNetscapeExt() {
    do {
        readBlock();
        if (block[0] == 1) {
            // loop count sub-block
            int b1 = ((int) block[1]) & 0xff;
            int b2 = ((int) block[2]) & 0xff;
            loopCount = (b2 << 8) | b1;
        }
    } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
}

/**
 * Reads next 16-bit value, LSB first
 */
protected int readShort() {
    // read 16-bit value, LSB first
    return read() | (read() << 8);
}

/**
 * Resets frame state for reading next image.
 */
protected void resetFrame() {
    lastDispose = dispose;
    lrx = ix;
    lry = iy;
    lrw = iw;
    lrh = ih;
    lastPixmap = image;
    lastBgColor = bgColor;
    dispose = 0;
    transparency = false;
    delay = 0;
    lct = null;
}

/**
 * Skips variable length blocks up to and including next zero length block.
 */
protected void skip() {
    do {
        readBlock();
    } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
}

public Animation<TextureRegion> getAnimation(PlayMode playMode) {
    int nrFrames = getFrameCount();
    Pixmap frame = getFrame(0);
    int width = frame.getWidth();
    int height = frame.getHeight();
    int vzones = (int)Math.sqrt((double)nrFrames);
    int hzones = vzones;

    while(vzones * hzones < nrFrames) vzones++;

    int v, h;

    Pixmap target = new Pixmap(width * hzones, height * vzones, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);

    for(h = 0; h < hzones; h++) {
        for(v = 0; v < vzones; v++) {
            int frameID = v + h * vzones;
            if(frameID < nrFrames) {
                frame = getFrame(frameID);
                target.drawPixmap(frame, h * width, v * height);
            }
        }
    }

    Texture texture = new Texture(target);
    Array<TextureRegion> texReg = new Array<TextureRegion>();

    for(h = 0; h < hzones; h++) {
        for(v = 0; v < vzones; v++) {
            int frameID = v + h * vzones;
            if(frameID < nrFrames) {
                TextureRegion tr = new TextureRegion(texture, h * width, v * height, width, height);
                texReg.add(tr);
            }
        }
    }
    float frameDuration = (float)getDelay(0);
    frameDuration /= 1000; // convert milliseconds into seconds
    Animation<TextureRegion> result = new Animation<TextureRegion>(frameDuration, texReg, playMode);

    return result;
}

public static Animation<TextureRegion> loadGIFAnimation(Animation.PlayMode playMode, InputStream is) {
    GifDecoder gdec = new GifDecoder();
    gdec.read(is);
    return gdec.getAnimation(playMode);
}
```

}

I call the gif like that:

```
Animation animation = GifDecoder.loadGIFAnimation(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP,Gdx.files.internal("data/BackgroundAnim.gif").read());
```

I already thought of asyncTask but I do not know how to use it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use AssetManager for this goal. You can see this tutorial for example [AssetManager](https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/asset-manager-libgdx-tutorial/). Try this, but as for my opinion .gif maybe not very flexible format. In my projects i just get a PNG from GIF, and then use normal animation.

Comment: Hallo, thanks for your response I have already found a solution for my Problem and I am using AssetManager now and preload my gifs. The Problem is that my Assetloader is blocking and I draw my loading screen after the gif is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate thread to run asset manager on.
Run the thread asynchronously and check to see if it's ready or not. If it isn't, draw the loading screen, otherwise, you're done!